# Config helper in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, helper

We have this existing project need to do maintenance and it is written in Laravel and so I am forced to learn since my base is CodeIgniter. So I came across this line

`echo config('global.header_title')`

from view which I believe a helper from config. Based on the doc here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values if you are echoing something like `config('global.header_title')` it means that, the source is

> config folder > global.php file > header_title variable (inside the array)

So I've been searching this `global.php` within the config folder but it is nowhere to be found. I was wondering if this is a helper or something else. Or maybe it's a helper but stored somewhere. But can a helper be stored at a different folder other than `config`?

Comment: that is just the default location for config files, they potentially could be loaded from anywhere, also you can set config values at run time ... i would do a project wide search for `global.php`, then a text search for `header_title`

Comment: @lagbox setting config values at run time, do you mean to be set from controller? If yes, I cannot find it in there also. Then the file must be kept somewhere else.

Comment: service provider, middleware, controller .. anywhere after the service providers finish the 'registration' process; i would look for `header_title` to find any hits